# Yeoman Generator CoffeeScript Entry Point

Tags: coffeescript, generator, yeoman

Is it possible to hook a 'index.coffee' file up as an entry point for a Yeoman generator?

The 'generator-generator' generator creates an 'index.js' file. Replacing it with a 'index.coffee' hides the generator from Yeoman.

I've looked in the documentation and couldn't find any mention of it.

https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Generators

I found a really old fork of Yeoman that seems to have had this planned:

https://github.com/mklabs/yeoman/wiki/generators

For the time being I've setup a watcher that compiles my CoffeeScript files into JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would want your `index.js` file to contain this:

```
require('coffee-script');
module.exports = require('./index.coffee');
```

Then put your actual generator code in `index.coffee`. I ported over the example from generator-generator here https://gist.github.com/tuxracer/6332601

Comment: Nice work porting generator-generator.  Care to turn on issues in github?  Got a few ideas.

Comment: @hurrymaplelad Thanks! Sure just turned them on

Comment: [As of CoffeeScript 1.7](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3349#issuecomment-34015414) you have to `require('coffee-script/register')` to load the compliler

Answer (score 0):

> For the time being I've setup a watcher that compiles my CoffeeScript files into JavaScript.

This is how you should do it. Yeoman/yo won't get "native" support for CoffeeScript. You can write your generator in CoffeeScript or any other language if you like, but you have to publish it as JavaScript to npm.

Answer (score 0):

Make `index.js` contain this:

```
require('coffee-script');
require('./generator.coffee');
```

Then put your code into `generator.coffee`.

Watchers is definitely NOT something you should do.